# css tab issue with selected tab

Tags: css, tabs

Hi I'm trying to style the tab sample i found on net.
here is the sample :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tabs 2</title>
    <style>
    body {
        font: 0.8em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    #header ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #header li {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
    }

    #header a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 1em;
    }

    #header #selected {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        background: white;
    }

    #content {
        border: 1px solid;
        clear: both;
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 1em 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This</a></li>
        <li id="selected"><a href="#">That</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p>Ispum schmipsum.</p>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

the problem is i want to add the background color for header and set it's width to 100%.
see the difference when i add this css code:

```
#header{
 width:100%;
 background-color:#b6ff00;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

before ( selected tab is merged with content )

[image: befor]

after ( selected tab has a border-bottom )

[image: after]

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's because you are adding `overflow:hidden` to header **and**
you haven't cleared floats*

below are solutions

**Clear:both**

**Here is definition of clear**

A common problem with float-based layouts is that the floats' container doesn't want to stretch up to accomodate the floats. If you want to add, say, a border around all floats  you'll have to command the browsers somehow to stretch up the container all the way.

Here is your **solution** and **A Quick Fix**

**"Clearing", 21st Century Style**

```
ul:after {
    clear: both !important;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Here is Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/g9N3r/4/

**Older Solution**

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This</a></li>
        <li id="selected"><a href="#">That</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
        <li class="clear"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p>Ispum schmipsum.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    background-color: #B6FF00;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}
.clear { clear : both; float:none !important}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/g9N3r/3/

I have just shown a quick clearing technique there are many others

You can see more ways http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: thanks a million, but the problem is the all of the top border of content removed this way, i want to just remove the part which conflicts with the selected tab